# fileInput widget shiny not working in webapp

Tags: r, deployment, shiny

I develop a shiny app with a fileInput widget.
this one works when I run my app (Run app, run in windows and run external too).

When I deploy my app on the web, this one works (I said that because, the download bar changes (we can see the download progression). But the file not appear ...

Do you have an idea ?

Here is a reproducible example :

ui.R

```
shinyUI( navbarPage("StatLab",inverse =T, fluid=T,position = c("static-top"),   #cerulean/spacelab/cosmo shinytheme("spacelab")


                    tabPanel("Introduction",

                             sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                                          br(),

                                          # tags$img(src="Groupe-Clarins-2015.png",height=200 , width=300),
                                          br(),
                                          br(),
                                          br(),
                                          textInput("titredoc", label=strong("Titre du document"), value="Entrez le titre du document genere")

                             ),
                             mainPanel(
                               h3("blablalba")


                             )
                    )
                    ,

                    #######onglet 2 load data #######
                    tabPanel("Chargement des donnees et mise en forme",
                             splitLayout( 
                               # width = 3,
                               shinyjs::useShinyjs(),style = "border: 1px solid silver;",
                               id = "side-panel",
                               cellWidths = c("0%","25%","25%", "20%","15%","15%"),
                               # cellWidths = 200,
                               column(6,

                                      fileInput('datafile', h4('Choix du fichier'), multiple=F),
                                      helpText("uniquement fichier xlsx/xls acceptes"), 


                                      actionButton("reset_input", "Reset"),
                                      helpText("Ce bouton permet de supprimer tous les choix") 

                                   )

                                   ),
                                 tags$hr(),

                                 mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('contents') 
                                 ))

    ))
```

here is the server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  library(xlsx)

  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      return(NULL)
    }

    read.xlsx(infile$datapath, sheetIndex=1, header = T)

  })

  #### pour visualiser la table
  output$contents <- renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(input$datafile)){
      return()
    }

    filedata()

  })

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })

})
```

More over, when i deploy in Rstudio:
I have this message:

```
    Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 96490...Detecting system locale ... DONE
Deploying bundle: 427631 for application: 96490 ...
Waiting for task: 180508025
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Installing packages
  building: Installing files
  building: Pushing image: 420587
  deploying: Starting instances
  unstaging: Stopping old instances
Application successfully deployed to 

Warning message:
Error detecting locale: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'raw'
 (Using default: en_US)
```

Comment: Hi  did you find some solution. I have the same error when deploying an app. I used txt and rds files still same error

Comment: If I remember It was another mistake in my code. I don't remember exactly what is it. Sorry.

Comment: But check on your JS console.